# Need to show Polling feature of Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, magento-enterprise, onepage-checkout, submenu

I need to show the **magento poll** to any of the pages of magento website. What code should I add to the PHTML files?

Answer (score 2):

One way to dispaly poll in different page is using xml. You can use the following code to display pole

```
<block type="poll/activePoll" name="right.poll">
            <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/active.phtml</template><type>poll</type></action>
            <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/result.phtml</template><type>results</type></action>
        </block>
```

Another way to display is create a static block and call it in the phtml file. In static block you can put the code

```
{{block type="poll/poll" template="poll/active.phtml" poll_id="1"}}
```

And the third way is using php code. I haven't tried it but found somewhere on net.

```
$action = Mage::getBaseUrl().’poll/vote/add/poll_id/’.$this->getPollId();
$poll = Mage::getModel('poll/poll')->load($this->getPollId());
$poll_answers = Mage::getResourceModel('poll/poll_answer_collection')->addPollFilter($this->getPollId())->getItems();
```

Comment: You can check this post. http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-frontend/reusing-magento-poll-on-any-page-or-any-block/